# Indexing SharePoint 2013 List Columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, large-lists, indexed-column

I have sharepoint list which has more than 40,000 item. Now the performance was very slow, So I planned to try Indexing to improve performances.

When I try to add the Indexing it's returning the following error.

I got this error details from ULS Log

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   0x80131904,
>   StackTrace:     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.UpdateCore(Boolean
>   bToggleSealed)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.EditIndexPage.CreateIndex(Guid
>   primaryField, Guid secondaryField)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.EditIndexPage.BtnCreate_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)      at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)      at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)

Pelase help me on this

Comment: Any chance you are running out of disk space on the SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior, you **can't** add indexes to columns if the total number of items is **more than 20,000** in SharePoint Server.

**Workaround to manage large lists**

- Create views with a filter that only shows items less than 5000 items.
- Using folders to organize data but it should also hold items less than the List View Threshold.
- Move the exceded list items to another list to make the main list less than 20,000 items. so

  - you can add indexes to the columns then
  - use the indexed column to filter your view. then
  - move the moved items back to the main list.

For more details, check

- [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)
- [Overview of lists and libraries with many items](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__bkmkchangelimit)